# A simple doubt on probability

Tags: probability

> How is $$P(A \cap B' \cap C')+P(A' \cap B \cap C')+P(A' \cap B' \cap C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2[P(A \cap B)+P(B \cap C)+P(C \cap A)]+3P(A \cap B \cap C) $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Venn diagram looks as follows:

[image]

The following identities hold, because probabilities of disjunctive variables sum up to the probability of their union.

$$\begin{align}P(A) & = P(A \cap B' \cap C') + P(A \cap B \cap C') + P(A \cap B' \cap C) + P(A \cap B' \cap C') \\
P(B) & = P(A' \cap B \cap C') + P(A \cap B \cap C') + P(A' \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
P(C) & = P(A' \cap B' \cap C) + P(A \cap B' \cap C) + P(A' \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
P(A \cap B) & = P(A \cap B \cap C') + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
P(B \cap C) & = P(A' \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
P(A \cap C) & = P(A \cap B' \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) 
\end{align}$$

Substituting these identities in the right-hand-side of your equation shows the correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a Venn diagram with three circles, all intersecting.  There should be eight regions, including the outside.  Then go through all eight regions, and decide how many times each region is counted on the left-hand side, and how many times it is counted on the right-hand side.  For example, $A\cap B\cap C'$ is counted on the right-hand side once in $P(A)$, once in $P(B)$, minus twice in $2P(A\cup B)$, or zero times in all.

Comment: I want theoretical proof